# Why the price of a room at weekend is not mentioned?

Tags: bookings, hotels

I'm going to [book a room](https://ca.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?q-check-out=2017-09-23&tab=description&hotel-id=270876&q-room-0-adults=1&YGF=14&q-check-in=2017-09-19&MGT=4&WOE=6&WOD=2&ZSX=0&SYE=3&q-room-0-children=0#) at a hotel (from 19-23th September) whose price per night is $113, but the booking website has noted no price for 23th September as below:

[image]

What is the meaning of that `-` sign?!

What is the price considered for that night?

Comment: You gave your dates as Sep 19-23, meaning you will be checking out on Saturday Sep 23.  Thus you will not be staying at the hotel on the night of Saturday Sep 23, so the price for that night is irrelevant.  It's an odd UI thing that it puts a box there, that's all.

Comment: @NateEldredge: So if the check out time is noon, then this result assumes that I will leave before 12 pm of Sept. 23th, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the normal way that hotel reservations are described.

Comment: Exactly. if you want to check out after check out time, you need to ask the hotel, and depending on their policies and how busy they are, it could be anything from "stay an extra two hours for free" to "we would have to charge you full price for another night."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have searched for a stay from the 19th to the 23rd. That's four nights, and each night costs $113 CAD. You're not staying at the hotel on Saturday night, and therefore there won't be a charge on Saturday. The "-" sign is simply filling the empty space on the web page.

Hotels.com always seems to show it this way. Here's what I see if I search for six nights instead:

[image: six night stay: four empty boxes]